# Apply rules to list of parent classes

Tags: less

I have the below LESS stylesheet and I know there has to be a better way to organize this.  Is the only option to create a map containing the classes and a mixin perhaps to repeat the styles?

```less
// child div is injected by JS
    .ddemrcontent > span, .blocksmarttemplate > span, .blocktoken > span {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 1.7rem;
        margin-top: 0.2rem;
        padding-left: 0.2rem;
    }

    .ddfreetext {
        display: flex;
        min-height: 1.7rem;
        margin-top: 0.2rem;
    }

    .ddemrcontent > span:hover, .blocksmarttemplate > span:hover, .blocktoken > span:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .ddemrcontent > span {
        border-left: 4px solid cadetblue;
    }

    .blocksmarttemplate > span {
        border-left: 4px solid burlywood;
    }

    .blocktoken > span {
        border-left: 4px solid #8a7090;
    }

    .ddfreetext {
        border: 1px dashed black;
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Here is the best I've been able to come up with.  Since the & parent selector won't apply to each distinct parent selector (that are comma delimited) I think I am forced to use a mixin and call it to apply the rules for each parent I have.
Would love to hear if there's still a better way.

```less
.dyndoccontent(@color) {
    & > span {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 1.7rem;
        margin-top: 0.2rem;
        padding-left: 0.2rem;
        border-left: 4px solid @color;

        &:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}

// child div is injected by JS
.ddemrcontent {
    .dyndoccontent(cadetblue);
}
.blocksmarttemplate {
    .dyndoccontent(burlywood);
}
.blocktoken {
    .dyndoccontent(#8a7090);
}

.ddfreetext {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 1.7rem;
    margin-top: 0.2rem;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend mixin if you have multiple parts in your less files which use the same styles.
For you example i would go for a more nested way:

```
// child div is injected by JS
.ddemrcontent, .blocksmarttemplate, .blocktoken {
    & > span {      
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 1.7rem;
        margin-top: 0.2rem;
        padding-left: 0.2rem;
        
        &:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}

.ddfreetext {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 1.7rem;
    margin-top: 0.2rem;
}

.ddemrcontent > span {
    border-left: 4px solid cadetblue;
}

.blocksmarttemplate > span {
    border-left: 4px solid burlywood;
}

.blocktoken > span {
    border-left: 4px solid #8a7090;
}
```

Comment: I tried something like that but the problem is that LESS doesn't appear to "expand" the parent, comma-separated classes when using the & parent selector.  Instead, it uses that entire parent selector as-is.  Hence, my thought about looping over a Map to apply the classes to each selector within the Map.  See my OP for what I've come up with at the moment.

Comment: a good idea for the dynamic color! i tried the nested part from me in codepen and it works as i would expect it
https://codepen.io/deibl31/pen/LYjRLRZ

Comment: Thanks for verifying.  Must be due to the version of LESS (2.7.1) that is utilized by the build system we use.  CodePen uses 3.10.0 it appears (at the time of writing)

Comment: oh good to know but does this solve your problem?